# Redirect page to homepage using htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule setup which works well:

```
RewriteRule ^circuit/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([^/]*)$ /circuit.php?id=$2 [L]
```

What I would like though, is if someone went to http://www.example.com/circuit.php that it redirects to the homepage, but if someone went to http://www.example.com/circuit/some-circuit/3 for it still to work.

I've tried simply using this approach:

```
Redirect /circuit.php http://www.example.com/
```

And this works in redirecting circuit.php but it also stops the dynamic pages working, I'm sure there is a simple answer for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /circuit\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^circuit/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([^/]*)$ /circuit.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```